# FK constraint fails while inserting into child on Disjoint tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, constraint

I'm trying to test the concept of disjoint tables in MySQL, so I created some tables:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type ENUM('label', 'checkbox') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'label',
  PRIMARY KEY (id, type)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE label (
  item_id INT NOT NULL,
  item_type ENUM('label') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'label',
  reviewer INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id, item_type, reviewer),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (item_id, item_type) 
                    REFERENCES `item` (id, type) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE checkbox (
  item_id INT NOT NULL,
  item_type ENUM('checkbox') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'checkbox',
  reviewer INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id, item_type, reviewer),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (item_id, item_type) 
                    REFERENCES `item` (id, type) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

I had no problems inserting into the *parent* table:

```
INSERT INTO item VALUES(1,'checkbox');
```

But if I then try to insert into the *child* table:

```
INSERT INTO checkbox VALUES(1,'checkbox',1);
```

I get a "constraint failed" error:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (checkbox, CONSTRAINT fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (item_id, item_type) REFERENCES item (id, type) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I've re-read my DDL several times and I can't find what is it that I'm doing wrong.
**What am I missing?**

I tried this in sqlfiddle.com, which means MySQL 5.6.

Also, since I have a box with 5.0.45 and phpMyAdmin at hand, I tried inserting with the GUI (in case I was messing up something else) but got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equal both `type ENUM` values.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `item` (
>   id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   type ENUM('label', 'checkbox') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'label',
>   PRIMARY KEY (id, type)
>   );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE checkbox (
>   item_id INT NOT NULL,
>   item_type ENUM('label', 'checkbox') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'checkbox',
>   reviewer INT NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY(item_id, item_type, reviewer),
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (item_id, item_type) 
>                     REFERENCES `item` (id, type) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
>   );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO item VALUES(1,'checkbox');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO checkbox VALUES(1,'checkbox', 1);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c71e2e8817a793eb980887de0dab515b)*

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I overlooked the possibility that the enums were simply different types.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a complimentary remark to @McNets answer, it's not a critique of his answer, just a note on why ENUM is a bad choice of data type. Let's add the `label` table to the equation:

```
CREATE TABLE label (
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    item_type ENUM('label', 'checkbox') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'label',
    reviewer INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(item_id, item_type, reviewer),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (item_id, item_type) 
                REFERENCES `item` (id, type) 
                    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

This works in the sense that we can now add an item of type label, and a corresponding label. However, nothing prevents us from adding a row like:

```
INSERT INTO label VALUES(1,'checkbox', 1);
```

So, the ENUM type is of no use when it comes to type control.

Comment: To make matters worse, in MySQL:" _The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines._"